# How to get last two rows of each key in google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to retrieve the last two rows of each SKU, how can I achieve this? By using the below query getting only a single last row of each SKU.

```
SELECT
  agg.table.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    sku,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(table)
    ORDER BY
      ReportstartDate DESC)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] agg
  FROM
    `BigQuery.PreviewReport` table
  GROUP BY
    sku )
```

Comment: If you already use `array_agg`, did you try [`limit n`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg)?

Comment: @astentx yes I checked with the limit but no result, giving only two rows of full table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `qualify`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `BigQuery.PreviewReport` t
WHERE 1=1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY ReportstartDate DESC) <= 2;
```